# Gulp doesn't detect change

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-watch

I have a problem with my Gulp installation. On running SASS, it detects change, run `gulp-sass`, but dosen't push any change, and says the following:

```
[17:48:30] Starting 'sass'...
[BS] 0 file changed ()
[17:48:30] Finished 'sass' after 12 ms
```

As you can see, there are 0 file changed, but files have been changed in my editor. I also try to close the process, and run again, not working.

I am using [jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync](https://github.com/shakyShane/jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync) stack. All was working.

You can see all the files [here](https://github.com/DevINX/devinx.co).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 common reason why sass auto-watch doesn't work:

1. You add a new sass file while watching
2. Your sass files are in the folder which is not set in gulp config
3. You are not at the tab where browserSync is currently serving

Since you said you've re-run the gulp process, we can cross out the first cause. And if you can see the terminal show `0 file changed` AFTER you change a file, we can then cross out the third cause. So chances are you just did not put the sass files in the right place.

You may first check whether your sass files are in the folder which is set in your `gulpfile`. An easy check is to clone the project and run it locally as the example shows, if it does work, then it must be the path issue.

Comment: It was a error between `sass` and `scss`. It was so small that I event didn't noticed! Thanks